# Numerous sticky scrolling divs jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a website whose homepage shall display a part of the many posts. The posts will be on the left side and the social buttons on the right side. The social buttons remain fixed as long as the part of the post is finished. You can understand me better by viewing this jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uhCsa/ . The following is my code :-

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-content">
    This is example content<br />
    This is example content<br />
</div>

<div class="right-content">
    This is the right content. I want this to scroll down as the user scrolls till the        
end of the main div
</div>

</div>
```

This is only a part of the code. Please view the entire code and the output in my jsfiddle. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below css to set the particular div is scrollable and another one is fixed.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scrollable {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #333;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    .fixed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 180px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #fa2;
    }
</style>
<div class="scrollable">
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    <div class="fixed">and I'm fixed</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: You did'nt get my problem. I do not have one such div, I have an unlimited number of divs. I also want the fixed div to stop scrolling after the main div is ended. You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/uhCsa/. I hope you get my point. Anyways, thanks for trying to help me..